# Create WiFi AP in Termux with root access

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering, termux, hostapd

For some purpose, I want to create a WiFi access point on my Android because I cannot turn on the hotspot when WiFi is enabled. And also I tried to use NetShare, but it cannot be enabled on boot.

I have hostapd binary in my Android in `/vendor/bin/hw/hostapd` and I tried it, but it doesn't turn on when WiFi is enabled.

How to create WiFi AP programmatically without NetShare (app).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Wi-Fi and hotspot at the same time on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/201024/how-to-use-wi-fi-and-hotspot-at-the-same-time-on-android)

Comment: [How to create a wifi hotspot from the terminal?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217896/218526)